# run 2 forever-running functions in 1 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

let's say that i have 2 async functions:

```
async def run1():
    run_forever(bot)

async def run2():
    run_forever(server)
```

this is not the actual code,
i need to run this 2 functions for a discord bot, which will run forever and a websocket server that receives the keystrokes of the client associated with the server that will play a soundboard effect in a voice channel neither of these can work without the other, how can i make so that both functions run for an unlimited amount of time while remaining asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) of asyncio.

this example should do about what you need:

```
def run_bot():
   run_forever(bot)

def run_server():
    run_forever(server)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await asyncio.gather([
        loop.run_in_executor(None, run_bot),
        loop.run_in_executor(None, run_server),
    ])

asyncio.run(main())
```

if both functions are in fact async (altough they are missing await statements), it's even easier:

```
async def run1():
    run_forever(bot)

async def run2():
    run_forever(server)


asyncio.run(asyncio.gather([run1, run2]))
```

Comment: the 2 functions need to remain async, as i already stated in the question